# Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 - requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups

Tags: ios, delphi, provisioning-profile

I created a Share extension type app in xcode and embedded it into my delphi (10.3.3.) project. (PlugIn folder)

In Ad Hoc mode it works,

In App Store mode

When I compile for the app store if I add "embedded.mobileprovision"  in deployment configuration then I get this error.

[PAClient Error] Error: E0776 Error Domain=IDEProvisioningErrorDomain Code=9 ""yashare.appex" requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups feature." UserInfo={IDEDistributionIssueSeverity=3, NSLocalizedDescription="yashare.appex" requires a provisioning profile with the App Groups feature., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Add a profile to the "provisioningProfiles" dictionary in your Export Options property list.}

I checked the provisionings they﻿ are correct,s .   both (app and extension) supports  group

If I disable  "embedded.mobileprovision" for appex in deployment  then delphi compiles the ipa correctly, however, when I try to upload IPA files to the store I get this error.

ERROR ITMS-90164: "Invalid Code Signing Entitlements. The entitlements in your app bundle signature do not match the ones that are contained in the provisioning profile. According to the provisioning profile, the bundle contains a key value that is not allowed: '4WXQVJ6QJ7.it.diesys.youaddict.yashare' for the key 'application-identifier' in 'Payload/YaApp.app/PlugIns/yashare.appex/yashare'."

In xcode everything looks fine